# Multiple functionality together at a time

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

If I would like to do number of function at a time without much loading then for that which option is best (for the purpose of less loading, fast execution & crash issues)...

1). NSThread

2). performSelectorInBackground

3). NSOperationQueue

Or any other than the above all? Please suggest me the best & the appropriate solution. Thnaks in advance for all the links & guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grand Central Dispatch would be the best I think.

```
// Job 1
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    // Heavy work here...

});

// Job 2
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    // Heavy work here...

});
```

And if you want to do something on the main thread from within those (eg. updating UI), use:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // Update UI...

});
```

Comment: Thanks...but by this I am not getting properly, will you please suggest any example or link?

Comment: [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) works by submitting [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) of code to the system to let it handle when to run them, so you don't have to...